# Customizing trackpad behavior

Tags: interface, customization, osx

I'm using a track pad. The settings I had for moving around, zooming, etc. were two finger pinch for zoom, one finger touch and drag for moving around.

Now I can only scroll up and down to zoom! How do I change the setting back to how it was? It was fine an hour ago. Maybe I accidentally pressed something.

Comment: Are these blender settings or settings for you track pad?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and reloading the factory settings did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'm assuming that these are blender settings.

To fix your problem, I would start with **load factory settings**. Loading the factory settings will reset every thing to the default settings. You can then customize from there.

[image]